# Getting Bad Request while trying to consume REST API in Java SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring-boot, rest

Hi I am trying to consume a REST endpoint using POST, but I am getting the error below. The endpoint gives proper response in POSTMAN, but I am getting error in Java. Please let me know where the mistake is.

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{
  "error":"unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description":"The given grant_type is not supported"
}]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 Bad Request: [{
  "error":"unsupported_grant_type",
  "error_description":"The given grant_type is not supported"
}]
```

Below is code:

Controller:

```
public class MemberController {

private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberController.class);

@Autowired
MemberService memberService;

@PostMapping(value = "/token",  headers = "Accept=application/json")
public String getToken() {
    log.info("Test getToken method");
    return memberService.callTokenService();
}
```

Service Class:

```
public class MemberService {    
    private static final Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(MemberService.class);    
    private RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();    
    final String tokenURL = "-------";    

    public String callTokenService() {

        log.info("Inside Service");
    TokenInput input = new TokenInput();
    
    String clientId = "l7xxef159fc30ee8479e9a7dab859c458a4d";
    String clientSecret = "a63d0b4a01b844c0b7e7eb724ef13959";
    String grantType = "client_credentials";
    
    input.setCLIENT_ID(clientId);
    input.setCLIENT_SECRET(clientSecret);
    input.setGRANT_TYPE(grantType);
    

    ResponseEntity<TokenProperties> response = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenURL,  input, TokenProperties.class);
    HttpStatus status = response.getStatusCode();
    
    log.info("Status: "+status);
    log.info("Response: "+response.toString());

    return response.toString();
    }

    

}
```

POJO class:

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(ignoreUnknown = true)  
public class TokenProperties {    
    String access_token;
    String token_type;
    String expires_in;
    String scope;
    public String getAccess_token()
    {
        return access_token;
    }

    public void setAccess_token(String access_token)
    {
        this.access_token = access_token;
    }

    public String getToken_type()
    {
        return token_type;
    }

    public void setToken_type(String token_type)
    {
        this.token_type = token_type;
    }

    public String getExpires_in()
    {
        return expires_in;
    }
    public void setExpires_in(String expires_in)
    {
        this.expires_in = expires_in;
    }

    public String getScope()
    {
        return scope;
    }

    public void setScope(String scope)
    {
        this.scope = scope;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "{" + "access_token='" + access_token + '\'' + ", token_type=" + token_type + ", expires_in=" + expires_in + '\'' + "scope='" + scope + '}';
    }

}
```

TokenInput POJO:

```
package com.memberservice_v2;
```

public class TokenInput {

```
String CLIENT_ID;
String CLIENT_SECRET;
String GRANT_TYPE;

public String getCLIENT_ID() {
    return CLIENT_ID;
}
public void setCLIENT_ID(String cLIENT_ID) {
    CLIENT_ID = cLIENT_ID;
}
public String getCLIENT_SECRET() {
    return CLIENT_SECRET;
}
public void setCLIENT_SECRET(String cLIENT_SECRET) {
    CLIENT_SECRET = cLIENT_SECRET;
}
public String getGRANT_TYPE() {
    return GRANT_TYPE;
}
public void setGRANT_TYPE(String gRANT_TYPE) {
    GRANT_TYPE = gRANT_TYPE;
}
```

}

Can anyone please help me out? Please let me know where the mistake is. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: Your TokenProperties class appears to be unused.

Comment: @tgdavies: I edited it, but still the same issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request `ResponseEntity<TokenProperties>  response = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenURL,  null, TokenProperties.class);` to token endpoint is incomplete. You're not passing the *payload* (token request) as far as I can see in the aforementioned code.

First, create the token request and set the appropriate attributes such as *client id, grant type* etc.

```
TokenRequest tokenRequest = new TokenRequest();
// set the attributes as per the token endpoint

ResponseEntity<TokenProperties>  response = restTemplate.postForEntity(tokenURL,  tokenRequest, TokenProperties.class);
```